# SQLite "SELECT" wrapper function returns empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, electron

I'm making a simple app using Electron with Node.js and SQLite 3. My goal here is to wrap up a basic `SELECT` query with my function. However, it fails to get content from the database.

I know that I can select the `firstname` column of a row like this:

```
storage.all('select firstname from users where id = 1', [], ( err, rows ) => {
    if ( err ) {
        throw `Error while retrieving ${q}`;
    };
    rows.forEach(( row ) => {
        n.webContents.send( 'userName', row.firstname );
        console.log( 'query output sent: ' + row.firstname );
    });
});
```

`storage` in here is my set-up database. The above works well and allows me to send my user name to my frontend view.

But if I wrap it into a function like the following:

```
let select = ( items, db, where, sign, whereNew ) => {
    // preset sql query
    let q = `select ${items} from ${db}`;
    if ( where && sign && whereNew ) { q += ` where ${where} ${sign} ${whereNew}`};
    let arr;
    console.log(q);

    // perform query on the database
    return storage.each(q, [], ( err, row ) => {
        if ( err ) {
            throw `Error while retrieving ${q}`;
        };
        return row[items];
    });
};
```

Then the output on my console will be an empty `Database` object (see below).

This is how I call this function and log it in the console:

```
let u = select( 'firstname', 'users', 'id', '=', 1 );
console.log( 'this log ' + u );
```

And this is the console output:

```
> szwaczki-react@0.1.0 dev /Users/middleman/Documents/Programowanie/MyApps/szwaczki-react-sqlite
> concurrently "BROWSER=none npm run start" "wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron ."

[0]
[0] > szwaczki-react@0.1.0 start /Users/middleman/Documents/Programowanie/MyApps/szwaczki-react-sqlite
[0] > react-scripts start
[0]
[0] Starting the development server...
[0]
[1] Connected to the database.sqlite
[0] Compiled with warnings.
[0]
[0] ./src/app.js
[0]   Line 2:  'ReactDOM' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
[0]
[0] ./src/view/button.js
[0]   Line 2:  'ReactDOM' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
[0]
[0] Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
[0] To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.
[0]
[1] select firstname from users where id = 1
[1] this log [object Database]
[1] query output sent: Mateusz
^C[0] BROWSER=none npm run start exited with code 0
[1] wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron . exited with code 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please show console.log(q) output

Comment: I've edited oryginal post to add these information

Comment: `[object Database]` in a console output does not indicate an empty object. It just says that that object is an instance of `Database`. However, it seems odd that the return value of that query is a `Database` instance and not a string like the result of the former. And besides that, the [`each` function does not seem to take 3, but rather two arguments (documentation)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3#usage)...

Comment: funny thing is I am getting the same output when I remove second parameter and even if I use 'all' function instead of each. So if it's not an empty object and it contains some kind of returned content, how do I retrieve it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `each` function returns a `Database` object to allow for chaining, not the `return` value of your callback function ([as per the documentation](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaseeachsql-param--callback-complete)).

To fix this, and due to SQLite's asynchronous behaviour, you can wrap the SQLite API function into a `Promise`, await it and then return the value you want to retrieve:

```
async function select (items, db, where, sign, whereNew) {
    // preset sql query
    let q = `select ${items} from ${db}`;
    if (where && sign && whereNew) {q += ` where ${where} ${sign} ${whereNew}`};

    console.log(q);

    // perform query on the database
    function fetch () {
        return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
            storage.each(q, [], ( err, row ) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject (`Error while retrieving ${q}`);
                } else {
                    resolve (row [items]);
                }
            });
        });
    }

    try {
        const result = await fetch ();
        return result;
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
}
```

---

BTW, it is not a goot idea to build an SQL query like that, as it is open to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should "prepare" your queries, for example by using the [`Database#prepare (...)` function](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databasepreparesql-param--callback), which basically ensures that no SQL code other than your query can be executed (by escaping any special characters, commands, etc.).

Comment: Thank you. The above code throws error "await is only valid in async function". As for the danger of SQL injection - app template I am building is a desktop software that won't be connecting to any network. Plus I am testing SQLite3 :) But thank you for this tip, I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I kinda answered my own question but I still have small problem with it. I have followed async clue and here is working code:

**JS**

```
storage.select = function ( items, db, where, sign, whereNew ) {
    let that = this;
    // preset sql query
    let query = `select ${items} from ${db}`;
    if ( where && sign && whereNew ) { query += ` where ${where} ${sign} ${whereNew}` };

    return new Promise ( function ( resolve, reject ) {
        storage.each( query, [], function ( err, row ) {
            if ( err ) { reject( err )}
            else resolve( row );
        })
    })
};

const result = storage.select( '*', 'users', 'id', '=', 1 )
    .then( row => { l( row ) })
        .catch( err => { l( err ) });
```

This works fine if I want to log te result or send it to IPC.Renderer. But I can't put it into variable or anywhere else on the backend, which is the idea behind this struggle.